# Photoshop action to resize images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, photoshop-scripting

I need to do the following:

- Take a folder of images
- Open images into Photoshop
- Adjust to 1000 x 1000 pixels in size
- Export and save as a high quality .jpg image into another folder (to
  keep it neat)

Images are all different sizes but I want to make sure that at least one side is 1000 pixels as it is for an eBay image. I would think that the largest side should be 1000 pixels and then the other side would be proportional.

I have created an action but that action will make all images to square images but I have mentioned that many different size images so I need proportional one side.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to do in Bridge if you have it available.

- open up your folder in Bridge
- select all the images
- Right click > Export to hard drive, and you will get a bunch of options regarding which folder to export to, and which size (type 1000px in your case). This will resize your images to 1000px on the larger side and keep proportions.

Should be pretty straighforward.